# How to enter a value to a textbox from an external excel or YAML file in Appium?

Tags: python, automation, yaml, appium

I'm aware of the fact that it is possible to enter a value to a text box using Appium sendkeys.

Is it possible to pass values from an external excel or YAML file to these textboxes?

For example, I need to pass values to UN and PW text fields, so I use

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@text,"UserName") and contains(@class, "android.widget.EditText")]').send_keys("User@1234")
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@text,"Password") and contains(@class, "android.widget.EditText")]').send_keys("1234")
```

I have a YAML file which contains various combinations of UN and PW for different test scenarios.

```
 Row1:
     username: User@1234
     password: 1234

Row2:
     username: User@523
     password: qaz@143
```

How can I pass these values to the desires UN and PW text fields?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to pass values from an external excel or YAML file to these textboxes?

Yes. Python is able to extract data from an Excel sheet using [xlrd](https://pypi.org/project/xlrd/) and from YAML using [PyYAML](https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/), and you can send the extracted data with [Send Keys](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/actions/send-keys/).

If you have problems doing this and need help with that, you need to be *a lot* more precise about what you're doing, how your input data looks, what you've tried and what the problem is.

Comment: What's your problem with reading the YAML? As you show it, this is solvable using almost nothing but the example code from the PyYAML documentation. Mind that StackOverflow is here to answer specific questions, not to write the code for you.

Comment: I got my problem fixed already. Thanks for the response anyways.